# PHP - multi user login unable to detect type of user

Tags: php, session, authentication

I wanted to make a multi user login. At least 2 type of users that is admin and a user. When I tried to enter the username and password as an admin, got the error displayed as **'Username and Password Invalid'** instead. Same for user.

PHP

```
include_once 'config.php';
$error="";

if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    if(empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])){
    $error = '<div class="alert alert-danger">Username or Password is Invalid</div>';
    } else {
        $username= $_POST['username'];
        $password= $_POST['password'];

        $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=? AND password=? ");
        $stmt->bind_param("ss",$username,$password);
        $stmt->execute();

        $row = $stmt->fetch();

        $user = $row['username'];
        $pass = $row['password'];
        $id = $row['id'];
        $type = $row['typeuser'];

     if ($username==$user && $pass==$password){
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['username']=$user;
        $_SESSION['passsword']=$pass;
        $_SESSION['id']=$id;
        $_SESSION['typeuser']=$type;

        if($type=='admin'){
            header("Location: dashboard.php");      
        } else if ($type=='user'){
        header("Location: user_dashboard.php");
        }
     } else
        {
        $error = "Username or Password is Invalid";
        }   
    }
mysqli_close($con); // Closing connection
}
?>
```

FORM

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="" >

    <div class="page-content container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                <div class="login-wrapper">
                    <div class="box">
                      <div class="content-wrap">
                        <h6>Sign In</h6>                                
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Username" id="username" name="username"><br/>
                            <input class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" name="password"><br/>
                            <input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit" value="Login" name="login"><br><br>
                            <strong class = "text-danger"><?php echo $error; ?></strong>                                    
                        </div>
                    </div>                          
                    <div class="already">
                        <p>Don't have an account yet?</p>
                        <a href="signup.php">Sign Up</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>                  
    </div>
</form>
```

I don't know why this error is displayed since I did the code right.

Comment: show your form code also. And you have stored password without encryption?

Comment: @B.Desai i have added the form code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysqli `execute` and `fetch` is not same as `pdo` when you use
`execute` in mysqli you need to use `fetch` with `bind_result`. Try follwoing code/ change your

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=? AND password=? ");
$stmt->bind_param("ss",$username,$password);
$stmt->execute();

$row = $stmt->fetch();

$user = $row['username'];
$pass = $row['password'];
$id = $row['id'];
$type = $row['typeuser'];
```

To

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT username,password,id,typeuser FROM users WHERE username=? AND password=? ");
$stmt->bind_param("ss",$username,$password);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($user, $pass,$id,$type);
$stmt->fetch();
```